# Продолжение блока с другой стороны

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как продолжить `div` с другой стороны, если он вышел за пределы родительского блока?

На jquery, javascript - не важно.

[image]

Этак как пример. Мне нужно, чтобы если блок выходит за пределы, то та часть, которая вышла за пределы, появилась на другой сторон на одной высоте.
Думаю я объяснил понятно.

Comment: посимвольно или в том числе и по полсимвола ?

Comment: Например, квадрат размером 10px. Если какая-то часть этого квадрата выходит за пределы экрана, или родительского блока, то эта часть будет отображаться уже с другой стороны. Принцип игры 'змейка'.

Answer (score 11):

Как например с помощью одного лишь css.

**Для строки:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


[data-string] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 95vw;          /*  Меняем положение основной строки */
  white-space: nowrap; /*  Запрещаем перенос строки */
}

[data-string]:after { 
  content: attr(data-string); 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100vw;  
}

.string {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="string">
  <p data-string="Lorem ipsum.">Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

**Для фигуры:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


.box {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;            /* Ширина блока */
  height: 100px;           /* Высота блока */
  background: orangered;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 0;  
  left: 85vw;          /*  Меняем положение основной строки */
}

.box:after { 
  content: '';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: orangered;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100vw;  
}

.string {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="string">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Фигура с анимацией:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


.box {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;            /* Ширина блока */
  height: 100px;           /* Высота блока */
  background: orangered;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 0;              
  
  animation: go 5s linear infinite;
  
  /* Для движения в другую сторону */
  /*animation: go 5s linear infinite reverse; */
}

.box:after { 
  content: '';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0rem;
  left: -100vw;  
}

.string {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;0
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

@keyframes go {
  from { left: 0vw; }
  to { left: 100vw; }
}
```

```html
<div class="string">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Принцип действия правильно, но нужно с фигурами так сделать. Например, квадрат размером 10px. Если какая-то часть этого квадрата выходит за пределы экрана, или родительского блока, то эта часть будет отображаться уже с другой стороны. Принцип игры 'змейка'.

Comment: @Alex, добавила вариант и для фигуры

Comment: @Elena, так уж мешал пример... Или был на столько ужасен? (можно не реагировать на коммент, просто мысли в слух...)

Comment: @Air, все хорошо, не обижайтесь )), но такие правки не уместны! Дайте свой ответ!

Comment: А пользоваться чужими лаврами не в моих правилах...  Просто логика моего поведения исходила из того, что часто, встречаю вопросы в комментах от новичков, `а как сделать шо-бы в обратную сторону и шо-бы блок по высоте был меньше`)))  Мой ответ выглядел бы плагиатом.... И обижаться на девочек тоже не в моих правилах... Да и вообще обижаться...)))

Comment: @Air, пока вообще не известно подходит ли моя идея автору вопроса, будут комментарии - буду додумывать по возможности. А вставлять целый кусок своего кода в качестве правки - попытка изменить ответ! Еще раз без обид)

Comment: Какие обиды....))))  А ответ вполне подходит.... И реализовано красиво...

Comment: Можно было бы для общей гибкости общие стили для элемента и псевдоселектора `after` вынести отдельно в стили селектора `.box, .box:after` или просто некоторые значения в `:after` заменить на `inherit`. Дублирования всегда мешают гибкости стилей.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, так дайте свой вариант ответа

Comment: @Elena Это предложения по улучшению для вас или других участников, это совершенно не тянет на отдельный ответ.